# MessageBox not displaying the correct output in Python GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to use messagebox to display the output of my function however while the function displays in the terminal it doesn't display in the messagebox. Is messagebox the correct one or is there another function I should be using? I simply want the x words to display on the GUI.

```
#Imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from collections import Counter
from tkinter import messagebox
import collections

# Initialize the dictionary
wordcount = {}

#open Macbeth text file
file = open('Macbeth Entire Play.txt', encoding="utf8")
a= file.read()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()  # Call __init__() method in parent (tk.Frame)
        
        self.label = tk.Button(self, text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count)
        self.label.grid(row=0)
        self.open_btn = tk.Button(text='Compute', command=self.ask_count)
        self.open_btn.pack(pady=(30,10))
        self.exit_btn = tk.Button(text='Exit', command=master.destroy)
        self.exit_btn.pack()

    def ask_count(self):
        
        with open('Macbeth Entire Play.txt', encoding="utf8") as file:
            self.file_text = file.read()
        for word in a.lower().split():
          word = word.replace(".","")
          word = word.replace(",","")
          word = word.replace(":","")
          word = word.replace("\"","")
          word = word.replace("!","")
          word = word.replace("â€œ","")
          word = word.replace("â€˜","")
          word = word.replace("*","")
          if word not in wordcount:
              wordcount[word] = 1
          else:
              wordcount[word] += 1
        n_print = int(input("How many most common words are: "))
        print("\nThe {} most common words are as follows\n".format(n_print))
        word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
        for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print):
          print(word, ": ", count)
        messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: " == n_print)

        # Close the file
        file.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Count words")
    root.geometry('400x400+900+50')
    app = Application(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your first message box will print the result of the comparison `"The top words are: " == n_print`, which I imagine will be `false`. The second will just print `"The top words are: "`. I assume you intended to write the messages differently than you actually did.

Comment: @Kemp I want the messagebox to display the output of my function inside of the GUI instead of just in the terminal

Comment: you're using the correct functions from `tkinter.messagebox`. However looks like you may wanna rethink the logic there as kemp tried to assess.

Comment: @CoolCloud how do you do that?

Comment: Please take a read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

I am not sure what you where trying to do using `==` but it should be:

```
messagebox.showinfo(f"The top words are: {n_print}")
```

Or even:

```
messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: "+n_print)
```

**Reason:**

The mistake is that when you say `"The top words are: " == n_print` it means you are comparing a string with `n_print` and it will return `True` or `False`. So you're asking `messagebox` to display `False` which is a `bool` and it fails to display `bool`s and hence you are getting an empty messagebox. See:

```
[In] : "The top words are: " == n_print # Assuming n_print = 'hey'
[Out]: False
```

As long as `n_print` is `"The top words are: "`, it will always return `False`.